# How to use wolframAlpha solve the following equation?

Tags: optimization, differential-equations, pde

$\dot A(t)=rA(t)-\frac{A(t)^2}{4c}+1$

$\dot B(t)=rB(t)-aA(t)$,

Where A(T)=q, B(T)=0, r,q,a,c, are parameters.

Suppose that r=0.02, q=2, a=10,c=1.2.

Question:

1. How to determine the A(t) and B(t).
2. In this case, it is possoble to use mathematic programming to solve it, such as MATLAB and so on.

Thanks a lot.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7BDivide%5Bd%2Cdt%5DA%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%3D2A%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29-Divide%5BPower%5BA%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C4%5D%2B1%2CA%5C%2840%29T%5C%2841%29%3D8%7D

Comment: If I want use parameters, not mumerical solutions？ How to do it?

Comment: Alpha will accept the parameter too.